# What is this way of assignment called? myVar(value);

Tags: c++, class, assignment-operator

I was digging in somebody else's code where I noticed he assigns the public/private members of a class in the following way:

```
myMemberVar(Value);
```

instead of

```
myMemberVal=Value;
```

I'm wondering if this way of assigning is normal and can be really used interchangebally.

Comment: That is not a way of "assigning" at all! So, without seeing any context, we cannot say _what_ it is.

Comment: Post a complete function, so that we can see the context.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: You are correct, that this isn't a assignment. but saying "it isn't it at all", isn't that correct too. You can't know what a method does internal by its prototype. so it could jsut be a kind of geter- / seter- method as known from C#. You know what i mean? OP isn't regarding to that(and his question) clear enough.

Comment: @Zaibis: No, it is totally correct. The tokens `myMemberVar(value)` can never be "an assignment". If it is a function call that internally performs some "set" operation then fine but that's not "an assignment"; it's a function call. And in fact it's clear from his comment on my answer that he _is_ "regarding to that". :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Thats what I said, but it could anyway behave as one could.

Comment: @Zaibis: That doesn't really matter!

Answer (score 2):

It's likely that you're looking at *initialisations* in the *member initialisation list*.

```
struct A
{
   int x, y;

   A()
     : x(42)    // <-- here
     , y(12)    // <-- and here
   {}
{};
```

These are not "assignments", any more than the following are assignments:

```
void foo()
{
   int x = 42;
   int y = 42;
}
```

But recall that the C++03 initialisation syntax (as opposed to the above confusing, legacy, looks-like-assignment syntax<sup>†</sup>) is:

```
void foo()
{
   int x(42);
   int y(42);
}
```

And, going further, since C++11:

```
void foo()
{
   int x{42};
   int y{42};
}
```

And that's the syntax that's *required* in the member initialisation list.

Note that this means they're *not* generally interchangeable: only in an initialisation! Usually when you write `=` you're performing assignment and this initialisation syntax would be invalid there.

---

<sup><sup>†</sup> Don't worry, I still prefer it too!</sup>

Comment: @yaro: Note that this means they're _not_ generally interchangeable. Usually when you write `=` you're performing assignment and this initialisation syntax would be invalid there.

Comment: I think you meant `int x{42};` as the *truly* modern syntax?

Answer (score 0):

That is the syntax for *construction*, not assignment.

Comment: Except it's missing a type in the general case. So in fact that is not the syntax "for construction" (you never invoke a constructor directly, even though the grammar sometimes misleads you into thinking you can). At _best_ you could say syntax "for declaration" but it's not even that because it does not have a declarator. It's an initialiser plain and simple.

Answer (score 0):

The first snippet of code doesn't assign anything; it attempts to call `myMemberVar` like a function.

Perhaps the real code was in the initialiser list of a constructor:

```
MyClass() : myMemberVar(Value) {}
```

while the second was in the constructor body:

```
MyClass() {
    myMemberVar = Value;
}
```

The difference here is that the first performs direct-initialisation, not assignment; the second performs default-initialisation followed by assignment.

For simple types, both have the same effect, and can be regarded as interchangable. For class types, they might call different user-defined functions: a conversion/copy/move constructor in the first case, and a default constructor followed by an assignment operator in the second. Depending on how those functions are defined, the two options may have different effects or performance characteristics, and may not be possible if the required functions aren't accessible.